# How does javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaBuilder#or work?

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, java-8, hibernate-criteria, criteria-api

I've created a custom repository to filter a list of entities from the db. Below is a basic initialization of the implemented class (entities are reduced to letters for clarification):

```
@Repository
public class CustomXRepositoryImpl implements CustomXRepository {

    private final EntityManager em;
    private final CriteriaBuilder builder;
    private final CriteriaQuery<X> query;
    private final Root<X> root;

    @Autowired
    public CustomXRepositoryImpl(EntityManager em) {
        this.em = em;
        builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
        query = builder.createQuery(X.class);
        root = query.from(X.class);
    }
}
```

and the method I implemented:

```
@Override
public List<X> filter(FilterParams params) {

    List<Predicate> restrictions = new ArrayList<>();

    // some if-statements ...

    if (params.getY() != null) {
        Expression<?> path1 = root.get("a").get("b").get("y");
        Expression<?> path2 = root.get("c").get("d").get("y");
        Predicate p1 = builder.equal(path1, params.getY());
        Predicate p2 = builder.equal(path2, params.getY());
//        restrictions.add(p1); // 3 results for Y = 4
//        restrictions.add(p2); // no result for Y = 4
        restrictions.add(builder.or(p1, p2)); // no result
    }

    // more if-statements ...

    query.where(restrictions.toArray(new Predicate[0]));
    return em.createQuery(query).getResultList();
}
```

What makes me confused is the fact that `builder.or(p1, p2)` returns no result, even though `p1` is satisfied. I also find the CriteriaBuilder#or [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html#or-javax.persistence.criteria.Predicate...-) (*Returns a disjunction of the given restriction predicates*) very ambiguous.

Can anyone explain this behavior?